# Remove href with jquery when clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, click, href

I want to **remove/disable** a **href**  with jquery, when the **link** is **clicked**. Actually no big problem.
But the link I want to remove is in a calender (the events calender).

That means when I use month view and open the site, the following code works:

```
$(".tribe-events-month-event-title").attr('href', '').css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'pointer-events' : 'none'});
```

But when I select another month like July the code doesn't work anymore.
So I thought why not trigger the link to be removed when clicked (Or is there a better way?), but I can't find a propper snipped that works. I'm new to coding and don't really know where to start looking.

**Link to Calender:** http://wpshindig.com/

**The html where I want to remove the href:**

```
<h3 class="tribe-events-month-event-title"><a href="http://wpshindig.com/event/contribute-to-wordpress/2017-06-08/" class="url">Contribute to WordPress</a></h3>
```

**Kinda Solution:** Couldn't solve it with jQuery... BUT

For everybody wondering how to remove the link in the events calender go to: plugins/the-events-calendar/src/views/month there you copy the folder you want to change: day, list, month. Then create a folder in your child theme called "tribe-events", edit single-event.php and replace link with #

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are using the class of `H4` tag not `a` for removing `href`

Try below code and let me know.

```
$(".tribe-events-month-event-title").find("a").attr('href', '').css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'pointer-events' : 'none'});
```

**EDIT 1**

Add `onClick` event on `<a>` Tag like below:

```
<h3 class="tribe-events-month-event-title"><a href="http://wpshindig.com/event/contribute-to-wordpress/2017-06-08/" 
 onclick="this.href=''" class="url">Contribute to WordPress</a></h3>
```

Comment: the code works BUT **not** if I **switch** to another **month**. Not the whole site reloads but the calender itself does. That's why I need a code that **removes the link when clicked**. This code only works in the first loaded month view.

Comment: Add this line of code in the event that change the month also.

Comment: I really don't know where. I'm still a noob. Isn't there a way to remove the link when the hyperlink is clicked?

Comment: So, you want href to be blank once link is clicked?If so, is the page refreshing on click of link?

Comment: Exactly. No the page should not refresh. It simply should do nothing :)

Comment: Please try my EDIT 1 in answer and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: that would only work if I change the php. I could add on click with jquery but the same problem with "changing the month" would appear.

Comment: can you share the change event of Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove href for anchor.Just change your code 
`$(".tribe-events-month-event-title a").css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'pointer-events' : 'none'});`

This code will work perfect.

Comment: Also you  can use css to remove. `.tribe-events-month-event-title a{ 'cursor': 'pointer'; 'pointer-events' : 'none'  }`

Comment: the code works BUT **not** if I **switch** to another **month**. Not the whole site reloads but the calender itself does. That's why I need a code that **removes the link when clicked**. This code only works in the first loaded month view.

Comment: You can use dynamic on click event and e.preventdefault

Comment: tried this one `$(document).on("click", ".tribe-events-month-event-title" function() {
 $("a").click(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr("href");
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on("click",".tribe-events-month-event-title",function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```